# Long time in installing azureml-sdk[databricks] on DataBricke

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks, azure-sdk, azureml-python-sdk

I am trying to install "azureml-sdk[databricks]" on my cluster in DataBricks using PyPi. But it is taking very long time and the status is always "Pending". I have waited around 2-3 hours but this package is still not installed.

Some other packages I can install easily using the same procedure. As you can see in the picture.

[image: Pending Status for azureml-sdk[databricks]]

[image: Configuration of Cluster in DataBricks]

Could anybody tell me that what could be the problem ?

Thanks !!!

Comment: Do you want to continue with the Version 11.1ML Databricks versions only?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are correct, it seems like a bug. I tried to reproduce the same in my environment it took a very long time.

[image: Ref]

You can reach out to [Azure Support](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/support/create-ticket/) or Can raise a [GitHub Issue](https://github.com/features/issues).

**Or**

You can follow below alternative approach. I successfully installed  `azureml-sdk[databricks]` using the 10.5 ML  Version.

> Azure Databricks Runtime Version: 10.5 ML (includes Apache Spark
> 3.2.1, Scala 2.12)

[image: Ref]

[image: Ref2]